# When I Try to Change the Color of SnackBar TextView App Crashes

Tags: android, android-snackbar

the error in logcat :

```
10-20 13:51:31.926 12874-12874/com.project.android.tourism E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
10-20 13:51:32.110 12874-12874/com.project.android.tourism E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.<init>
```

and code :

```
TextView textViewSnack = (TextView) findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);   

textViewSnack.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(PlaceActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

You need to pass `view` of **`SnackBar`** to find the `textView` of **`SnackBar`**.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(
                    coordinatorLayout,
                    "Snackbar: floatingActionButton1 (normal) clicked",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED); //to change the color of action text
View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(PlaceActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Comment: thank you for answering me . but my code exactly like this , first i get view of snackbar and try to change the attribute of textview exactly like you

Comment: but look at your code you did not mentioned snackbar.findviewbyid

Comment: can you post your complete code in your question again

Comment: Thank You Buddy , Yes I Forget it That Part. I Changed it Now And Run Perfectly Thank You Very Much.